# How many concurrent RDP Connections on Windows 7 Pro, Enterprise and Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise and Ultimate offer Remote Desktop Server.

How many concurrent connections does this allow? Only 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, just one, the same as XP Pro does.  And it is the console session, so no one can be using the machine interactivly while someone is connected to it by RDP.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Concurrent RDP Patcher](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/enable-remote-desktop-connection-in-windows-7-home-premium/) to get more that just one RDP connection.