# Run outlook as remote application on Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Is it possible to run Outlook as a remote application over RDP to Windows 7 Enterprise?

I'd like to set up an .rdp file to run Outlook from my work laptop (Win7E) on my home computer (Win7U).  I generally don't need use anything else off the work laptop when I'm at home, but I don't want to install Outlook on my home computer.

I saw [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/123229/how-many-concurrent-rdp-connections-on-windows-7-pro-enterprise-and-ultimate), which notes the fact that there is only one connection allowed at a time, which is fine for what I want to do because no one else will be connecting to the laptop.  It also mentions that the available connection uses `/console`, which I'm afraid may preclude me from running a windowed application instead of a full desktop connection.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, it appears that Outlook is not a good candidate for running as a remote application if you're using .ost files.

Comment: So, have you actually just tried this yet?  It should be fully possible and easy to do.  I use several programs from a Vista machine via the standard RDP RemoteApp setup, and they work better than expected.  The /Console switch means you'll be connecting to the "Console" session (the one you use if you're at the keyboard and monitor), instead of a (new) RDP session. It doesn't mean you'll end up at some text-only 'console' or terminal window. :)

Comment: I haven't actually tried it yet.  My google skills have been poor this afternoon, and I can't find a template or anything to start from.  I took that to mean that people didn't really do it :)  Based on your comment, I'll probably spend some time this evening putting together a basic .rdp file to see if I can get it working.  I just haven't put that time in yet.

Comment: @techie007 - I got it to start, following the instructions at http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2009/12/18/137048.aspx and using the tool described therein.  However, after outlook opens, it fails with messages about not being able to open the ost files, and then immediately closes.  Have you run outlook this way?