# Multiple users via RDP

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Here is my example scenario:

I have a WIN 7 Pro computer with 3 different accounts:

- John
- Jack
- James

This computer sits on a desk on its own and users RDP onto the machine.

James is already RDP'd on to the machine on his own profile
John wants to RDP onto the machine and login with his profile

John wants to use MS Paint and draw something
James is already RDP'd on and is using Excel.

Is it possible for John to RDP on to the same machine and do whatever tasks he needs whilst James is currently on the machine too?

I'm aware this will involve some dll hacking however is the above possible?

Can what I am asking to be achieved using the machine to run 3 virtual machines, then RDP on to the individual Virtual Machines?

Comment: The feature you are looking for is called [Remote Desktop Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd640164(v=ws.10).aspx) and is only available in the server versions of Windows.

Comment: Well, it is _technically_ present in all versions, it's how the fast user switching works – the 'consumer' ones just have a 1-active-session limit which can be patched out. I used to do that on WinXP.

Comment: Also see: [How many concurrent RDP Connections on Windows 7 Pro, Enterprise and Ultimate?](http://superuser.com/questions/123229/how-many-concurrent-rdp-connections-on-windows-7-pro-enterprise-and-ultimate)

Comment: One question per "question" please.  the majority of what you've asked ahs already be asked/answered a few times.  As for you second question, yes you could run 3 VM's and RDP into each of them. What makes you think you couldn't? What has your research shown you?  You haven't provided enough information for that question for us to provide anything but a general answer of "yes, you could", so as-is that part wouldn't make a good stand-alone question.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible for John to RDP on to the same machine and do whatever tasks he needs whilst James is currently on the machine too.

For a supported *Windows 7* setup, **no, this is not possible.** Non-server versions of Windows are limited to one active user at a time, as stated in [How to Enable Concurrent Remote Desktop Sessions in Windows](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/how-to-enable-concurrent-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows.html).

> Unlike server editions of Windows, Microsoft limits the client editions of Windows to one concurrent user, whether remote or local. So if a remote desktop connection is made, no one physically at the PC can use it or even see the desktop without first kicking off the remote user.

The workaround offered at the linked page involves replacing a core Windows component with one published by an anonymous developer, which I would **absolutely advice against** as you have no idea what other changes might have been made, including the potential for malware being injected into the binary, as well as that any system update could potentially break the setup. You would also highly likely be in violation of the Windows license terms.

If you don't want to run a server version of Windows, you could potentially get **a similar result by virtualizing several copies of Windows** on top of a sufficiently powerful computer and giving each user access to their own instance. This will have the additional benefit (in some use cases, at least) of isolating the activities of each user from that of the others.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

Terminal Services, or Remote Desktop Services, requires a Server OS, and Microsoft wishes, licenses for each users connecting to the machine.

If there were "dll hacking" involved, it would require essentially convincing the system it is a server OS.

If you don't have to stay with RDP, there are third-party apps that add this functionality. I have not used any of them myself, but they were a simple Google search away and may be worth trying with appropriate considerations and caveats:

http://www.thinstuff.com/products

Comment: Is it not possible to have the machine run 3 different virtual machines and then RDP on to each virtual machine? If that makes sense.

I have a licence for Windows Server 2003 and the install disk somewhere around here, is this the best route for me to go?

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows Server instead.  It's much better for multiple RDP sessions and other services.

Comment: I presume that Windows Server 2003 would suffice? I still have a licence and cd for this.

Comment: It's approaching end of life.  It'll work though.

Comment: @user2416214 Note that [Windows Server 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003) is at best eight years old (with SP2 applied) and is about to exit extended support. I would not recommend using it.

Comment: I am aware that it's on its way out support wise, however I literally just need it for this one task, no mail exchanges or anything fancy.

I have an application and 3 licences for said application
I want the ability to remote on as a user who has a licence and allow for other users to connect at the same time.

I hope this makes sense it's been a long day!

Comment: For Server you only get two Administrator accounts logged in at once.  You'll also need RDS CALs on top of your user CALs, and setup the Remote Desktop Server services, if you want regular/more users to be able to RDP (legally).